# what is the cause of this kind of error: redefinition of 'function' as different kind of symbol

Tags: c++

I have a Node represents a point on the Map, and I want to write a function to get the Euclidean Distance between two Nodes, I have written this Code, but It didn't Work, I don't know why !
Can you help please ??

*Header Part*

```
struct Node1{
  double longitude;
  double latitude ;
  double ID;
  std::string name;
};

double distance_function(Node1 , Node1);
```

*CPP Part*

```
Node1 ND1,ND2;
double distance_function(ND1, ND2){
  double dist = 0;
  dist = sqrt(pow((ND2.latitude - ND1.latitude),2)+pow((ND2.longitude - ND1.longitude),2));
  return dist;
}
```

The Error Says : Distance_Function.cpp:10:
**error: redefinition of 'distance_function' as different kind of symbol**

Comment: Please include enough code for everyone to reproduce the problem but without anything irrelevant, also called [mcve]. Further, I'm noticing that you are writing the type (`Node1 ND1, ND2`) before the function using these as parameters. This is not valid C++ but an ancient and obsolete C syntax. If you have any tutorial or book using that syntax, stop using it, because modern compilers will reject it. Lastly, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the data types in function definition also :)

```
double distance_function(Node1 ND1, Node1 ND2)
{
  double dist = 0;
  dist = sqrt(pow((ND2.latitude - ND1.latitude),2)+pow((ND2.longitude - ND1.longitude),2));
  return dist;
}
```